Advices on KeyCloak broker configuration for SSO from external SAML and 2 keycloaks
I have a case when users need to login via Okta to broker where I have configured instance of keycloak having SAML IDP initiated SSO.
Broker would need to redirect on successful login to one of 10 instances of KeyCloak installed in every tenant. I have configured between broker KeyCloak and tenant KeyCloak OpenID Connect (OIDC) SSO.
Now I am looking for a way to connect it end 2 end so that user from Okta got successful SAML SSO and on successful login is redirected to tenant KeyCloak via OIDC.
I am looking for advise or hint on how to do it or what features to use. Unlikely there are instructions for it but if you know them and could share I would be extremely grateful

simply, flow after the configuration is User Login to Identity provider (Okta) -> gets SAML Response back to keycloak -> validate SAML Response -> generate authentication_code from keycloak using OIDC -> use authentication_code to exchange for a token.
Please let me know If you need step wise suggestion I will be glad to help you.
